# Graphml parse error

Tags: python, igraph, graphml

I tried to create a graphml file using python and igraph library. I can construct igraph's graph object and wrote it to a file using:

```
g.write_graphml("mygraph.graphml")
```

Everything seems to be successful but when I tried to read the file back to python using:

```
g = Graph.Read_GraphML('mygraph.graphml')
```

I got this error:

```
igraph.core.InternalError: Error at .\src\foreign-graphml.c:1024: 
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xA0 0x3C 0x2F 0x64
```

How can I solve this, please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any special characters (e.g., accented letters or letters from Asian scripts) in your vertex or edge attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I already see the libary source code. I think library can output only UTF-8 XML Encoding. So all character must be UTF-8 encoding and if some non-UTF-8 character contains in file, Errors will be raised.

The Solution:

You should convert all string in your python application to UTF-8 encoding before use as describe [here](http://goo.gl/J3nPg)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem should come from Unicode invalid bytes sequence problem but without your file I can only guess.

I think you may load string from non-Unicode encoding file and use it directly without convert to Unicode encoding. Please try convert these strings to Unicode by see this post.

[a busy cat http://goo.gl/CFGYf](http://goo.gl/CFGYf)